# u-boot can I get a function to run after my display is init

Tags: c, u-boot, vxworks

Is there a way in u-boot to get a functions to run after my display is initialized and my splash screen is up. If I call the function in  board_init() or board_late_init() my display has not yet initialized. I want to know if there is a way I can call my function after my splash screen is up?

Dennis

Comment: Which OS and version are you running. You can't really do this kind of thing through u-boot. You should look into init levels / rc.d / startup processes. For example: https://www.simplified.guide/linux/automatically-run-program-on-startup

Comment: U-boot is generating my splash screen, and I want to run a function after the splash screen is displayed but before it tries to boot vxWorks.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were running vxWorks, I had assumed Linux.  I can't really help you there. I'd recommend adding that tag to you post.

Comment: I need to run this function before vxWorks starts, but after the splash screen is displayed.